# G Hub macro on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, automation, mouse, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

I want to use G Hub's macro feature on ubuntu, but I couldn't launch it using wine. And for some reason I couldn't use piper. I am currently using Logitech G102 LIGHTSINK. If somebody knows how to use G Hub on ubuntu or another solution that can use macro like G Hub, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I have also faced the same issue for my Logitech G-402 Hyperion  Fury. I tried Bottle and wine latest version to install Logitech G Hub but unfortunately that couldn't install the Logitech G Hub apps on my Linux Device (Based on ubuntu 22.04). I also tried Piper (a linux apps for mouse configuration on linux/ubuntu) and was frustrated. Then I found  a solution. I install Logitech G Hub on another windows device and configured my mouse. Luckily I have a built in storage in my mouse and all the configuration saved to my mouse and I can use on my Linux Device now. One thing, after configuration from a windows device now I can also configure the programmable keys only in piper. But be sure lighting effect will not work in Piper. I didn't see your device supports built in memory. If that supports then you can give that a try like me. If you can configure well on a  windows device then it should work. Bottom line, so far logitech apps are not for linux/ubuntu so far. I tried bunch of  apps and  spend over a week. All the best.

Comment: Well, I tried that, but internal memory didn't support macro.

Comment: But, I was using ubuntu because my cpu wasn't good enough(makes to many lags on windows lol), but I'm gonna upgrade my computer so I think I don't need it anymore :D

Comment: @R0K0Rlee I am not clear. Did you applied the same I did (configured on a Windows pc and using on a linux PC) ?